# Bash: merging two tables with pipe and based on two different columns

Tags: bash, sorting, join

I know this question has been asked before in various ways but I could not find a solution so far.

I have two files without headers which I want to left join on two different columns, but `join` complains that my files (or one of them) is not sorted yet.

Another thing is that I need to use the first file in a pipe (that is why I use `cat` in my example below.

Here are my two files

```sh
# out1
Ad_12351    gnl|Prokka|Ad_18
Ad_12368    gnl|Prokka|Ad_18
Ad_12369    gnl|Prokka|Ad_18
Ad_80878    gnl|Prokka|Ad_6311
```

```sh
# out2
gnl|Prokka|Ad_1 NODE_1_length_1532695_cov_20.805081 100.000 1532695 0   0   1   1532695 1   1532695 0.0 2.830e+06
gnl|Prokka|Ad_2 NODE_2_length_1110392_cov_51.706023 100.000 1110392 0   0   1   1110392 1   1110392 0.0 2.051e+06
gnl|Prokka|Ad_3 NODE_3_length_1073395_cov_25.049683 100.000 1073395 0   0   1   1073395 1   1073395 0.0 1.982e+06
gnl|Prokka|Ad_4 NODE_4_length_942458_cov_21.166101  100.000 942458  0   0   1   942458  1   942458  0.0 1.740e+06
gnl|Prokka|Ad_5 NODE_5_length_934614_cov_54.686741  100.000 934614  0   0   1   934614  1   934614  0.0 1.726e+06
gnl|Prokka|Ad_6 NODE_6_length_822594_cov_21.071332  100.000 822594  0   0   1   822594  1   822594  0.0 1.519e+06
gnl|Prokka|Ad_7 NODE_7_length_775953_cov_51.943039  100.000 775953  0   0   1   775953  1   775953  0.0 1.433e+06
gnl|Prokka|Ad_8 NODE_8_length_669799_cov_20.124807  100.000 669799  0   0   1   669799  1   669799  0.0 1.237e+06
gnl|Prokka|Ad_9 NODE_9_length_669094_cov_52.446878  100.000 669094  0   0   1   669094  1   669094  0.0 1.236e+06
gnl|Prokka|Ad_10    NODE_10_length_656226_cov_8.484500  100.000 656226  0   0   1   656226  1   656226  0.0 1.212e+06
gnl|Prokka|Ad_11    NODE_11_length_561745_cov_235.394513    100.000 561745  0   0   1   561745  1   561745  0.0 1.037e+06
gnl|Prokka|Ad_12    NODE_12_length_557414_cov_8.035369  100.000 557414  0   0   1   557414  1   557414  0.0 1.029e+06
gnl|Prokka|Ad_13    NODE_13_length_540856_cov_40.368085 100.000 540856  0   0   1   540856  1   540856  0.0 9.988e+05
gnl|Prokka|Ad_14    NODE_14_length_510936_cov_13.262043 100.000 510936  0   0   1   510936  1   510936  0.0 9.435e+05
gnl|Prokka|Ad_15    NODE_15_length_471976_cov_52.281100 100.000 471976  0   0   1   471976  1   471976  0.0 8.716e+05
gnl|Prokka|Ad_16    NODE_16_length_469438_cov_40.667960 100.000 469438  0   0   1   469438  1   469438  0.0 8.669e+05
gnl|Prokka|Ad_17    NODE_17_length_468675_cov_21.008559 100.000 468675  0   0   1   468675  1   468675  0.0 8.655e+05
gnl|Prokka|Ad_18    NODE_18_length_465405_cov_219.905046    100.000 465405  0   0   1   465405  1   465405  0.0 8.594e+05
gnl|Prokka|Ad_19    NODE_19_length_464169_cov_13.391522 100.000 464169  0   0   1   464169  1   464169  0.0 8.572e+05
gnl|Prokka|Ad_20    NODE_20_length_415362_cov_20.670704 100.000 415362  0   0   1   415362  1   415362  0.0 7.670e+05
gnl|Prokka|Ad_21    NODE_21_length_411782_cov_56.949841 100.000 411782  0   0   1   411782  1   411782  0.0 7.604e+05
gnl|Prokka|Ad_22    NODE_22_length_408727_cov_13.361336 100.000 408727  0   0   1   408727  1   408727  0.0 7.548e+05
```

Actually, the second file is much larger (around 100,000 lines).

Here is what I want to do: I want to join the two files based on the second column of `out1` and the first column of `out2`.

Joining without sorting gives me an error, because the files are not sorted, but the same thing happens when I try to sort both files before:

```sh
cat out1 | sort -k 2 | join -1 2 -2 1 - <(sort -k 1 out2)
gnl|Prokka|Ad_18 Ad_12351 NODE_18_length_465405_cov_219.905046 100.000 465405 0 0 1 465405 1 465405 0.0 8.594e+05
gnl|Prokka|Ad_18 Ad_12368 NODE_18_length_465405_cov_219.905046 100.000 465405 0 0 1 465405 1 465405 0.0 8.594e+05
gnl|Prokka|Ad_18 Ad_12369 NODE_18_length_465405_cov_219.905046 100.000 465405 0 0 1 465405 1 465405 0.0 8.594e+05
join: /dev/fd/63:11: is not sorted: gnl|Prokka|Ad_1     NODE_1_length_1532695_cov_20.805081     100.000 1532695 0       0       1     1
532695  1       1532695 0.0     2.830e+06
```

The same thing happens when I try to do that without pipes (it produces exactly the same error):

```sh
join -1 2 -2 1 <(sort -k 2 out1) <(sort -k 1 out2)
```

What I would like to have in the end is a table that looks like this

```sh
Ad_12351    gnl|Prokka|Ad_18     NODE_18_length_465405_cov_219.905046
Ad_12368    gnl|Prokka|Ad_18     NODE_18_length_465405_cov_219.905046
Ad_12369    gnl|Prokka|Ad_18     NODE_18_length_465405_cov_219.905046
Ad_80878    gnl|Prokka|Ad_6311
```

but I can also remove the other columns with `cut` later.

If someone has a solution with `awk` instead of `join`, this is also good.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ join -1 2 -2 1 -a 1 -o 1.1,1.2,2.2 <(sort -k2 out1) <(sort out2)
Ad_12351 gnl|Prokka|Ad_18 NODE_18_length_465405_cov_219.905046
Ad_12368 gnl|Prokka|Ad_18 NODE_18_length_465405_cov_219.905046
Ad_12369 gnl|Prokka|Ad_18 NODE_18_length_465405_cov_219.905046
Ad_80878 gnl|Prokka|Ad_6311
```

or, using awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {
  a[$2,++n[$2]]=$1
  next
}
($1 in n) {
  for(i=1;i<=n[$1];++i) {
    print a[$1,i],$1,$2
  }
  delete n[$1]
}
END {
  for(b in n) {
    for(i=1;i<=n[b];++i) {
      print a[b,i],b
    }
  }
}' out1 out2
Ad_12351 gnl|Prokka|Ad_18 NODE_18_length_465405_cov_219.905046
Ad_12368 gnl|Prokka|Ad_18 NODE_18_length_465405_cov_219.905046
Ad_12369 gnl|Prokka|Ad_18 NODE_18_length_465405_cov_219.905046
Ad_80878 gnl|Prokka|Ad_6311
```

Comment: Thank you, works fine. How can I use that if I want to pipe `out1`? `cat out1 | awk ... `?

Comment: @littlebird `cat out1 | awk '...' - out2`

Comment: can you verify your `sort` command? I get a not sorted error for `join`. Also, how can I use that if I want to pipe `out1` in the command?

Comment: @littlebird `cat out1 | sort -k2 | join ... - <(sort out2)`, this way it works with your samples